# Blank Rythm output when using @extends

Tags: java, spring-mvc, template-engine, rythm

I have an interesting problem.  I'm trying to integrate the Rythm template engine into my Spring MVC application, so I wrote a simple view resolver that invokes `RythmeEngine` to render files.  However, when I try to use `@extends(...)`, the engine returns a blank render.  I have two template files:

### layout.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Rythm Sandbox</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome!</h1>
    @render()
</body>
</html>
```

### rhythm.html

```
@extends(layout)
Hello World!
```

I am invoking `RythmEngine` as follows:

```
RythmEngine eng = RythmEngineFactory.getEngine();
File f = new File(someRootPath + name + ctx.getSuffix());
resp.setContentType("text/html");
eng.render(httpResponse.getWriter(), f, model);
```

And `RythmEngineFactory.getEngine()` returns a singleton `RythmEngine` with the following configuration:

```
Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<String, Object>();
props.put("engine.mode", "dev");
props.put("home.template.dir", myTemplateRootDirectoryPath);
return new RythmEngine(props);
```

## Problem

Here's the problem: without the `@extends(layout)` line in rhythm.html, I get a render "Hello World" as expected.  However, when I try to extend layout.html, it results in a blank render (i.e., no output at all).  I know it's finding the layout.html file, because if I replace `@extends(layout)` with something like `@extends(layoutGooBlah)`, the error message says "Cannot find extended template by name 'layoutGooBlah'".  So I know it's finding my template fine, but why would the output be blank??

## Edit:

Interesting phenomenon: when I change this line:

```
eng.render(httpResponse.getWriter(), f, model);
```

To:

```
String s = eng.render(f, model);
httpResponse.getWriter().write(s);
```

It works.  ???  Why won't it write to a `PrintStream` when using `@extends`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API engine.render(writer, ...) is buggy. See https://github.com/greenlaw110/Rythm/issues/201

BTW, I recommend you use http://github.com/greenlaw110/spring-rythm for your spring MVC application

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even know spring-rythm existed, this is great!

Comment: Unfortunately there is no documentation for spring-rythm yet. But there sample applications you can refer to: https://github.com/greenlaw110/spring-rythm-samples